# How to get photos or videos from tmp

Tags: rendering, animation, interface

I started a render without fully reviewing all the settings and I left the file output as /tmp\ is there any way I can get these files out of the /tmp\ folder?

Comment: You can browse to /tmp with any file manager (nautilus, finder, dolphin, etc.) and copy them. Are you getting any strange errors?

Comment: You can navigate to /tmp\ by typing %tmp% in your windows search bar. Your renders should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to figure this out myself. If you're on Mac, go to Macintosh HD in the Finder, then you need to reveal hidden folders (Command+Shift+.). This will show the tmp folder. Organize by file type to see the pngs (or whatever file type you saved). Should be there!